# Bash - How do I loop through subdirectories and extract the files

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a directory called 10K_TIF (main directory). Within this main directory are multiple sub-directories each containing tif images. I want to read each TIF image and extract its path using a bash command. 10K_TIF over 15TB in size.

Sample:

```
10K_TIF/4320cc/4320cc_01_rectified.tif
10K_TIF/4320cc/4320cc_02_rectified.tif
10K_TIF/4520cc/4520cc_01_rectified.tif
10K_TIF/4520cc/4520cc_02_rectified.tif
```

I managed to echo each sub directory, also managed to echo all tif images but these are in separate commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`:

```
find 10K_TIF -iname '*TIF'
```

To loop over the results and do something with each image, you can use:

```
find 10K_TIF -iname '*TIF' | while read tif; do echo "Found: $tif"; done
```

The above assumes sane file names, with no whitespace or strange characters. If your file names can include such characters, use this instead:

```
find 10K_TIF -iname '*TIF' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' tif; do echo "Found: $tif"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find 10K_TIF -iname "*.tif"
```

And if you want to process each file, like finding the content type of the file

```
find 10K_TIF -iname "*.tif" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 file
```

Or to calculate md5sum

```
find 10K_TIF -iname "*.tif" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 md5sum
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want (only) list all *.tiff files in all subdirectories with `bash` it is easiest to use `**` pattern (globstar):

```
shopt -s globstar
ls **/*.tiff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` for finding all files and passing them to whatever command you want to use by using

```
find 10K_TIF -iname "*.tif" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 <command>
```

This searches through `10K_TIF` and all subdirectories, matching everything that ends with `.tif` (case-insensitive) **and** is a regular file (ie. directories, special files and symbolic links ending with `.tif` are not processed).

If you want to process, for example, symbolic links and regular files, you can use

```
find 10K_TIF -iname "*.tif" \( -type f -o -type l \) -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 <command>
```